# How does the application permission system work on macOS?

Tags: macos, security, permissions, kernel

How does the permission system work?

Usually, when an app tries to do something, e.g access the camera or the microphone, it **has to ask the OS, which then asks the user.**

And also, if an app tries to gain access to a specific directory on the machine, it has to ask.

Some apps however, have access to some directories out of their own folder without asking.

For example, I try to set the output path for some image-manipulation program.

Without asking for permission, that program is able to write files to the chosen directory.

My questions are:

- How is that possible
- And what permissions do apps have by default?

Comment: “Some apps however, have access to some directories out of their own folder without asking.” Generally, if an application is signed by Apple, meaning Apple knows what the app is and what it does, it will not ask for permission. Typically the only time the permission request happen is when an application is not signed by Apple. Such as an application you installed on your own outside of the Apple App Store and such.

Comment: So you mean, that an application that is signed by apple by default has access to the whole machine?

Comment: “So you mean, that an application that is signed by apple by default has access to the whole machine?” Correct. But I am really just basing this on my own experience. Better wait for someone else to add more details.